# How can i see Timestamps in Unix files

Tags: unix, ubuntu

Files in UNIX filesystems have 3 types of timestamps: Access, Modify, and Change. In order to investigate this, I created a file and I want to look at timestamps  . Anybody knows how can i look the different timestamps. Then, which commands timestamps.

Comment: And also I want to know which command change the timestamp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `stat` command:

```
stat filename
```

Comment: `bash: stat: command not found` What if we do not have the `stat` command?

Answer (score 3):

to change the `atime` and `mtime`, use the `touch` command:

```
touch --time=atime -t 198805232211.45
touch --time=mtime -t 205012300945.30
```